# Google cloud platform individual billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

Hello I'm having a problem where i can not select individual as my payment profile and I'm forced to use business profile but I'm not able to create one since i don't​ have a tax ID how do i select a individual profile?

Comment: The best channel for your inquiry will be to reach out to the billing team at https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, are you by any chance in the EU? Sounds bizarre but looks like they only offer the service to those using it "for business purposes" in this region and that if you are using it without any potential economic benefit you should stop!

Source: https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions